# Запрет индексации в поисковиках

Tags: robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.php?*mod=order*
```

Запретит ли индексацию в поисковиках такая запись в robots.txt именно ссылки с переменной `mod=order`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запретить индексировать все ссылки которые имеют параметры `mod=order` вот таким выражение нельзя.

Comment: и как мне запретить индексирование таких ссылок?

Comment: Прописать все ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

[Яндекс поймёт звёздочку в Disallow](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=996567#996572)

[Гугл и некоторые другие тоже](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt?hl=ru-RU)

> Google, Bing, Yahoo, and Ask support a
> limited form of "wildcards" for path
> values

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, какие ссылки надо запрещать. Если требуется блокировать ссылки вида

> `.../index.php?sdfsdfmod=ordersadfsdf`

то такое правило должно их отсечь. Вы можете проверить это в средствах для вебмастеров Google и Яндекс.